# I got an error during Data migration from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento, magento2, database-migration, magento-1.9

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'm2loom_live.customer_entity_back' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT DISTINCT  `child`.`custome r_id` FROM `authorlogin_customer` AS `child`
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_back` AS `parent` ON child.customer_id = parent.entity_id WHERE (child.customer_id IS NOT NULL) AND (parent.entity_id IS NUL
L)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhK3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that table name (`m2loom_live`) I'm guessing that table comes from an extension or a customization you may have put in. Those tables need to exist before you can migrate their rows to your new database. To do that you will need to either install the Magento 2 version of that extension or recreate your module and add an install script (or better yet a db_schema.xml) file, and then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to create the table. Then you should be able to migrate the data to your new database.

If you don't want to keep that table then you will have to modify or extend the data-migration-tool's mapping files to tell it to ignore that table instead of trying to migrate its data. I'm not 100% on this part, but I think the mapping file you would want to edit would be `map.xml` and you would add:

```
<document_rules><!-- This is the element you need to add your configuration too -->
...
<ignore>
    <document>Your Table Here</document>
</ignore>
```